# Index replication and Load balancing

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Am using Lucene API in my web portal which is going to have 1000s of concurrent users.
Our web server will call Lucene API which will be sitting on an app server.We plan to use 2 app servers for load balancing.
Given this, what should be our strategy for replicating lucene indexes on the 2nd app server?any tips please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which contains built in replication. This is possibly the best and easiest solution, since it probably would take quite a lot of work to implement your own replication scheme.

That said, I'm about to do exactly that myself, for a project I'm working on. The difference is that since we're using PHP for the frontend, we've implemented lucene in a socket server that accepts queries and returns a list of db primary keys. My plan is to push changes to the server and store them in a queue, where I'll first store them into the the memory index, and then flush the memory index to disk when the load is low enough.

Still, it's a complex thing to do and I'm set on doing quite a lot of work before we have a stable final solution that's reliable enough.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, Lucene should have no problem scaling to thousands of users.  That said, if you're only using your second App server for load balancing and not for fail over situations, you should be fine hosting Lucene on only one of those servers and accessing it via NDS (if you have a unix environment) or shared directory (in windows environment) from the second server.

Again, this is dependent on your specific situation.  If you're talking about having millions (5 or more) of documents in your index and needing your lucene index to be failoverable, you may want to look into Solr or Katta.

Answer (score 1):

We are working on a similar implementation to what you are describing as a proof of concept.  What we see as an end-product for us consists of three separate servers to accomplish this.

There is a "publication" server, that is responsible for generating the indices that will be used.  There is a service implementation that handles the workflows used to build these indices, as well as being able to signal completion (a custom management API exposed via WCF web services).

There are two "site-facing" Lucene.NET servers.  Access to the API is provided via WCF Services to the site.  They sit behind a physical load balancer and will periodically "ping" the publication server to see if there is a more current set of indicies than what is currently running.  If it is, it requests a lock from the publication server and updates the local indices by initiating a transfer to a local "incoming" folder.  Once there, it is just a matter of suspending the searcher while the index is attached.  It then releases its lock and the other server is available to do the same.

Like I said, we are only approaching the proof of concept stage with this, as a replacement for our current solution, which is a load balanced Endeca cluster.  The size of the indices and the amount of time it will take to actually complete the tasks required are the larger questions that have yet to be proved out.

Just some random things that we are considering:

- The downtime of a given server could be reduced if two local folders are used on each machine receiving data to achieve a "round-robin" approach.
- We are looking to see if the load balancer allows programmatic access to have a node remove and add itself from the cluster.  This would lessen the chance that a user experiences a hang if he/she accesses during an update.
- We are looking at "request forwarding" in the event that cluster manipulation is not possible.
- We looked at solr, too.  While a lot of it just works out of the box, we have some bench time to explore this path as a learning exercise - learning things like Lucene.NET, improving our WF and WCF skills, and implementing ASP.NET MVC for a management front-end.  Worst case scenario, we go with something like solr, but have gained experience in some skills we are looking to improve on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating the Indices on the publishing Backend machines into the filesystem and replicate those over to the marketing.
That way every single, load & fail balanced, node has it's own index without network latency.

Only drawback is, you shouldn't try to recreate the index within the replicated folder, as you'll have the lockfile lying around at every node, blocking the indexreader until your reindex finished.